# Implicit variable declaration and ternary assignment

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have an implicit variable `yesCount` that is initialized by a ternary operator which returns an int or a decimal.

```
List<int> simulationsCounters= new List<int>();
simulationsCounters.Add(5);
var yesCount = simulationsCounters.Length > 0
     ? simulationsCounters[0]
     : 0m;
```

Why does the compiler always compile yesCount as a decimal ?
What process is it following to deduce this ?

Comment: "Why does the compiler always compile yesCount as a decimal " - because it has to "always" be *something* (the same something), and given `int` and `decimal`, the precedence rules say `decimal` (implicit vs explicit)

Comment: Those speech quotations cut me deep. I'll just give up on a career now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a ternary operator which returns an int or a decimal

That is not true. The ternary operator can only have *one* return type. So the compiler deduces this return type as `decimal`, because the secod part of your operator returns a `decimal` and the `int` of the first part can *implicitly* be casted to `decimal`.

And since the return type of that operator is `decimal`, your `var yesCount` is a `decimal`, too.

Comment: @theIrishUser don't know the implementation details, but afaik if the types are different and type a is implicitly castable to type b, then it chooses type b. If there is no implicit conversion between those two types, the compiler will raise an error.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks !

Comment: @theIrishUser sorry, wrong link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691313(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your ternary operator has two operands: an integer and a decimal. The right hand operand is a decimal since you postfix it with `m`, which means `decimal`.

The compiler is that smart it can use the implicit casts to determine which type is the best fit for the output variable. Since an `int` can be implicitly casted to a `decimal`, but not the other way around, a `decimal` is the best fit. The same is true for `float` vs. `double`. The `double` wins.

Comment: Aah, Perfect, Thanks !